# Map reducing does not work wether I close channel or not

Tags: go, indexing

This is homework and beginner question. I edited the question since I made a mistake that I found.

I am trying to do parallel frequency maps from a text and I get an error in the last operation (reducing maps)

The code seem to work up to this point.

If I close the channel I get error:
"panic: send on closed channel"

If I do not close the channel I get:
"fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!"

```golang
func WordCount(text string) {

    text = strings.ToLower(text)
    re := regexp.MustCompile("\\w+")
    sentence := re.FindAllString(text, -1)

    numberOfGroups := 4
    piece := len(sentence) / numberOfGroups

    wordChannel := make(chan map[string]int)

    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    wg.Add(numberOfGroups)

    for i := 0; i < numberOfGroups; i ++ {
        go processToCounting(sentence[i*piece:(i+1)*piece], wordChannel, wg)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Print(<-wordChannel)
    fmt.Print("\n")

    finalMap := make(map[string]int)
    close(wordChannel)

    for i := 0; i < numberOfGroups; i++ {
        for k, v := range <- wordChannel {
            finalMap[k] += v
        }
    }
}

func processToCounting(textSlice []string, wordChannel chan map[string]int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    freq := make(map[string]int)
    for _, v := range textSlice {
        freq[v]++
    }
    wg.Done()
    wordChannel <- freq
}
```

Comment: Oups, I made a channel instead of a map! That solved this. But I have now a new error, which is "panic: send on closed channel"

Comment: Seems to be solved by "defer close(wordChannel)". Why is that so? Isn't it what waiting groups are here for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. First question: panic**

> If I close the channel I get error: "panic: send on closed channel"

Why? One of you goroutines is trying to write to the channel which you already closed in the calling (main) goroutine. In your case in `WordCount` function.

In the current version of your code the `panic` [is not reproducible](https://play.golang.org/p/h4jkRmispEB) with my test sentence, but you can easily cause this e.g. if you would call `close(wordChannel)` before `wg.Wait()`.

Lets look at the **Bug** in `processToCounting` which may cause the `panic`:

```
wg.Done() // tells to the WaitGroup that the gouroutine is Done (decrements the counter of goroutines)
wordChannel <- freq // trying to write to the channel
```

Here `wg.Done()` signals to the `WaitGroup` that the goroutine is `Done` before actual writing to the channel has happened. The calling goroutine (`WordCount` function) at some point thinks that all gouroutines are done (`wg.Wait()` line) and closes the channel. But one of your goroutine which have not finished writing, will try to write to the closed channel. Then you will get the `panic`.

**How to fix:**

Use [`defer`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements) in `processToCounting` function

```
defer wg.Done() // triggers wg.Done right before the function returns (but after writing to the channel in your case)
```

**What to read:**

See for beginners in [A Tour of Go / Concurrency](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4)

> Sending on a closed channel will cause a panic.

and documentation for: [`close`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Close)

> Sending to or closing a closed channel causes a run-time panic.

**2. Second question: deadlock**

> If I do not close the channel I get: "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!"

You have a for-loop which reads from the channel. This for-loop is locked forever. Waiting for new values from the channel, but nobody will write there anymore.

See in [A Tour of Go / Concurrency](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4)

> The loop for i := range c receives values from the channel repeatedly until it is closed.

and see documentation for [Channels](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels)

> Receivers always block until there is data to receive

Answer (score 0):

Q1: why `close(wordChannel)` triggers a panic

A:

1. you put `wg.Done()` before pushing result into the channel
2. the channel is a non-buffer channel, which means that it will be stuck to write until there is a read. but the read happens after you close channel. the sequence is close channel -> read channel -> write channel -> panic

Q2: why there is a deadlock.

A: `fmt.Print(<-wordChannel)` read a msg from the channel, so that the last loop can't read `numberOfGroups` message. it waits for the last message forever.

```golang
for i := 0; i < numberOfGroups; i++ {
        for k, v := range <- wordChannel {
            finalMap[k] += v
        }
    }
```